# Unable to run JAVA on Raspberry PI Zero? "VM is only supported on ARMv7+ VFP"

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w, java

I am using Raspberry PI Zero W. I installed java 1.8 and 1.9 jdk's. Installation is successfully done. When i run the JAVA command on the RPi. Its shows error like:
**"Error occurred during initialization of VM
Server VM is only supported on ARMv7+ VFP"**

Please give me solution on the error?

Answer (score 4):

If you have installed java 8 and still can't seem to get the VM to run then try:

> > sudo update-alternatives --config java
> >
> > > > > Select java 8's menu number

Java 8 should work just fine thereafter

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Oracle has not released an up-to-date Java build that supports the BCM2835 (the CPU in the Pi Zero W). (See [Cannot execute or open .jar files](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100366/cannot-execute-or-open-jar-files), [Raspberry Pi 0 W and armv6](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=196887).)

It looks like there are three options in this instance. 1) Switch to a Raspberry Pi 2 or newer, which have an ARMv7 or better, and support the official JDK. 2) Switch to OpenJDK, an alternative to Oracle's JDK. 3) Try the old Java SE Embedded.

[To use OpenJDK](https://elinux.org/RPi_Java_JDK_Installation#Installing_OpenJDK_on_a_Raspberry_Pi_.28Debian_Wheezy_or_Rasbian_Wheezy.29):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

[To use Java SE Embedded](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/raspberrypi-1704896.html):

Download the latest release from [Oracle's website](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javaseembedded8u211-downloads.html), which at the time of writing this is ejdk-8u211-linux-arm-sflt.tar.gz. Unfortunately you'll need to register to do this. Extract it using `tar zxvf ejdk-8u211-linux-arm-sflt.tar.gz`. To run java then `cd jdk*/bin` and then `java -version` to get started.

Comment: Oracle actually did have a release for ARMv6 that ran on the model 1 Pis (which have the exact same CPU as the Zero), for java 7 and then 8.  There are references here about those going back to 2013.  I don't know how long the kept it up beyond that, but last I checked it was gone (and since ARMv6 is not widely used, it is very unlikely to be coming back).

Comment: Searching for 'jdk' does turn out some relevant results: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/91/is-there-a-jdk-with-a-jit-compiler-available and https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4683/how-to-install-the-java-jdk-on-raspberry-pi/ but they are a bit dated, the `oracle-java7-jdk` package is no longer in repositories. I think you could manually install it following the same direcitions from https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html though.

Comment: Now, its working fine, i degraded java version.

Comment: @Nagaraj Please accept the answer with a tick on the tick on the left side on it. This finished your question and show me and others that I don't have to look for a help to you anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I just installed Buster on my old Pi1 B+ and ran into the same problem.

after

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

the JavaVM didn't run.

I removed it and installed

```
sudo apt-get install java-8-jdk
```

now it starts.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, see [Java 11 not working](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/93821/java-11-not-working)

There doesn't seem to be a Java version for older Pi's and the zero as they use an ARM6 processor, while the newer boards have a 7 or 8 and those are completly different processors.